# Matrix assignment in rpy2

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpy2

With rpy2, in python 3.5, I can define an R matrix:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
m = robjects.r.matrix(robjects.IntVector(range(10)), nrow=2, ncol = 5)
print(m)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    4    6    8
[2,]    1    3    5    7    9
```

I can then [extract an element by row, column, R-style](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/robjects.html#extracting):

```
print(m.rx(1, 2))

[1] 2
```

And I can assign a value to an arbitrary element, Python-style:

```
m[4] = 100
print(m.rx(1, 3))

[1] 100
```

However, I can't figure out how to assign an element by row, column. I tried the following:

```
m.rx(1, 3) = 200
    m.rx(1, 3) = 200
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

and

```
m[0, 2] = 200
    m[0, 2] = 200
  File "/Users/xavier/python/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 261, in __setitem__
    res = super(Vector, self).__setitem__(i, value)
TypeError: VectorSexp indices must be integers, not tuple
```

How can I assign a value to a row, column of this matrix?

Comment: Googling `rpy2 rx` suggests `m.rx[1, 3] = 200` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should normally be described in the documentation.

Let us know if the following is not answering the question: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#assigning-r-style

Comment: The documentation is for vector and doesn't mention you can do m.rx[i, j], R-style indexing. However it works, as user2357112 mentioned.

Comment: Actually I'd like to add, the doc never suggests one can use two indices with a square bracket. The only time I see two indices it is with a round bracket after `.rx`, and that doesn't work for assignment. I suggest to simply add an Assignment subsection for matrices just after Extraction http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#extracting that can showcase the `.rx[i, j]` syntax.

Comment: @Calimo Thanks. I'll look into adding an example to the doc. Vectors, matrices, and arrays are pretty much the same thing (in R): a contiguous memory region with dimensions. You can also beat me to it and submit a pull request.